# Как хранить переменную в функциональном компоненте React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Как хранить переменную внутри реакт функционального компонента чтобы ее состояние гарантированно изменялось сразу?

Сейчас если вызвать setCount из

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

то переменная count в определенных местах остается старой.

```
Например setCount(5)
Затем setCount(3) 

count выводит 5, а не 3
```

Comment: Вы все правильно делаете, только помните, что изменение состояния компонента это асинхронная операция

Comment: А где хранить именно переменные которые будут точно заданы синхронно без задержки?

Comment: Можете привести пример, какого поведения вы хотите достичь? Если на пальцах, то переменные "здесь и сейчас" придется создавать заново, либо хранить в отдельном внешнем хранилище(Redux, useContext) или создать свое собственное. В мире React лучше сразу привыкать жить в асинхронности

Comment: Ну примерно так:
 Сейчас input поле с текстом генерирует 3 события при вводе поиска. 
A, AD, ADM 

и вот запрос A приходит самым последним и перезаписывает последний ADM. 
Хотя он запускался самым первым и уже не актуален.

Comment: Что то как то смутно в это верится. Можете в вопрос добавить минимальный пример, как вы определяете события и как понимаете, что приходит?

Comment: @manking что-то влияет на эту переменную. посмотри на чистый пример https://playcode.io/1074483

Comment: Ну тут я сам не знаю как устроен код. 
Есть глюк при поиске, отображается неправильно таблица если в поиске быстро вводить текст. 

Я в конкретной функции которая присваивает уже данные таблице вижу порядок присвоения такой:
AD, ADM, A

Если  вводить поиск медленно то все нормально работает порядок такой.
A, AD, ADM.

Соответственно хочу заблокировать  обновление если более новый запрос уже отработал, но нигде не получается установить переменную для блокировки старого запроса, у него все переменные старые внутри.

Comment: Так же не стоит забывать что при изменении стейта можно использовать функцию. Она принимает старый стеит и возвращает новый. `setCount(old => 5)`, `setCount(old => 3)` или `setCount(old => old + 1)`

Comment: Вот эмулировал поведение. 
https://playcode.io/1074643

Если ввести быстро 123
То через 2 секунды будет записано 1, а должно быть 123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Вот эмулировал поведение. Если ввести быстро 123 То через 2 секунды будет записано 1, а должно быть 123.

Потому что именно это вы и написали!

```js
if (ev.target.value === "1") {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setCount(ev.target.value)
  }, 2000)
} else {
  setCount(ev.target.value)
}
```

Что происходит, когда вы быстро (менее, чем за две секунды) набираете 123:

`ev.target.value = "1"`
Срабатывает первая ветка и запускает двухсекундный таймер по истечении которого будет вызвана `setCount("1")`.

`ev.target.value = "12"`
Срабатывает вторая ветка. Состояние обновляется почти мгновенно.

`ev.target.value = "123"`
Срабатывает вторая ветка. Состояние обновляется почти мгновенно.

Приблизительно через две секунды после того, как вы набрали 1, наконец срабатывает таймер, который и вызывает `setCount("1")`, а **не текущее значение инпута**.

Вот логи (добавил в ваш пример в начало `handleChange` два `console.log`):

```
Hello console
input=1
count=undefined
1
input=12
count=undefined
input=123
count=12
1-1
```

А теперь, отвечая на ваш вопрос:

> Например setCount(5)
> Затем setCount(3)
> count выводит 5, а не 3

Если вы обновляете один и тот же state два и более раз подряд, то стоит в `set`-функцию передавать не новое значение, а тоже ф-ю, которая принимает старое значение как аргумент и возвращает новое.

Пример:

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

function handleChange(e) {
  setCount(count + 1)
  setCount(count + 1)
}
```

Ожидаемый результат: `count` каждый раз увеличивается на 2.

Фактический результат: `count` увеличивается лишь на 1.

Причина: `state` обновляется асинхронно. На момент вызова второго `setCount` `count` всё ещё равен предыдущему значеню. Например, если `count` сейчас равен 0, то дважды вызывается `setCount(0 + 1)`.

Решение:

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

function handleChange(e) {
  setCount((count) => count + 1)
  setCount((count) => count + 1)
}
```

UPD:

> А как не меняя код функции handleChange добиться чтобы переменная count, имела значение 123, а не перезаписалась потом на 1 через 2 секунды?

Если вам не нужно обязательно ждать 2 секунды перед обновлением, то лучшим решением будет просто сразу обновлять состояние.

```js
function handleChange(e) {
  setState(e.target.value) // И никаких if else
}
```

Если вам из соображений производительности нужно, чтобы состояние обновлялось не сразу, тогда на помощь придёт такая конструкция.

Пример: мы хотим сделать поиск. Есть форма, туда вводится текст, который мы отправляем в запросе на сервер предоставить отфильтрованные данные.

Проблема: запрос отправляется при каждом изменении поля. Т. е. на одно слово wood у нас будет четыре запроса на сервер: w, wo, woo, wood.

Решение: `useEffect` и `timeout`.

```js
const [name, setName] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
    // творим, что душе угодно
    console.log("api call: " + name);
  }, 500);

  // обязательно очищаем предыдущий таймер
  return () => clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}, [name]);

function handleChange(e) {
  setName(e.target.value);
}
```

Вот статья на эту тему: [[React] Wait for User to stop typing then execute a function](https://eight-bites.blog/en/2021/06/wait-user-typing/).

А вот документация по `React.useEffect`: [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: А как не меняя код функции handleChange добиться чтобы переменная count, 
имела значение 123, а не перезаписалась потом на 1 через 2 секунды?

Comment: Обновил ответ, где и ответил на ваш текущий вопрос (в комментарии всё бы не влезло).

Comment: Т. е. короткий ответ: никак, ведь именно в этой ф-и завязана вся логика по обновлению состояния.

Comment: Ну да, сейчас все корректно расписано, через useEffect подойдет. Но тут функциональный компонент только так называется))) по факту там выполняется несколько запросов на сервер прямо внутри него, что и приводит к проблемам, после того как эти запросы в случайном порядке возвращаются  и начинается рендер таблицы несколько раз.

Comment: _Срабатывает первая ветка и запускает двухсекундный таймер по истечении которого будет вызвана setCount("1")._ - в блоке кода, который ты пример - это не так работает. и `ev.target.value` внутри setTimeout будет иметь последнее значение `123`

Comment: Зачем мне последнее значение ev.target.value?
Я же там присвоил переменную чтобы продемонстрировать проблему выполнения ассинхронного кода в функциональном компоненте. Надо быть внимательней.

Comment: @manking, обрати внимание, что комментарий был не тебе, а автору ответа, об ошибке в его ответе.

Comment: @Grundy, да, вы правы. Только что проверил, и даже с созданием переменной копии `ev.target.value` записывается последнее значение. Дело в том, что я не сразу обратил внимание на то, что у автора вопроса `input` неконтролируемый (есть `onChange`, но нет `value`), на что даже указывает ошибка, если поправить это: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Comment: В общем в вопросе смысл был узнать есть ли хоть какие то возможности внутри функционального компонента защититься от множественных внешних событий из-за которых нарушается порядок отрисовки компонента. Ответ: получается нельзя. Нельзя обращаться к глобальным переменным или статическим, а внутренний state работает ассинхронно и не гарантирует что переменная будет иметь актуальное значение в момент проверки.

Comment: Почему нет? В примере с `useEffect` там внутри всегда актуальные данные из `state`. Я бы вообще не парился по поводу того, что `state` обновляется асинхронно: это занимает немного времени, и компонент будет перерисован с новыми данными.